# Pasting HTML table from clipboard to Excel worksheet with VB.NET Application

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, encoding

I have a `DataTable` with 7000 rows and 60 columns, and I need to save it in an Excel file.

Looping through the `DataTable` takes to much time, and the [ClosedXml](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/) libary is raising an exception that I could not solve (for many weeks). So I have decided to create an HTML table from the `DataTable`, add it to the clipboard and paste it to the generic Excel file on the network.

**the problem is that all the strings are written in Hebrew, and when the app is pasting the data all the strings don't encode properly, and Excel presents them as question marks.**

Note: When I paste the data that the application set on the clipboard using my mouse the data is pasted like it should, without question marks. 
Also I have tried to use all the Enum parameters of the `PasteSpecial()` method without success.
Please see the relevant code parts I have added.

```
 Public Function LoadDataTableToDivisinReport(ByVal d As DataTable, ByVal pathAndFileNameToSave As String, ByVal DbsheetNameToReplaceData As String, Optional ByVal pathToSaveImages As String = "") As Boolean
........

                Dim t As Threading.Thread
                t = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf createHtmlTableToClipBoard)
                t.SetApartmentState(Threading.ApartmentState.STA)
                t.Start()
                ws.Range("a1").PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteFormats)

.........
End Function


    Private Sub createHtmlTableToClipBoard()

        Dim b As New StringBuilder
        b.Append("<table>")
        b.Append("<tr>")
        For i = 0 To dd.Columns.Count - 1
            b.Append("<th>" & dd.Columns(i).ColumnName & "</th>")

        Next
        b.Append("</tr>")



        For j = 0 To dd.Rows.Count - 1
            b.Append("<tr>")
            For i = 0 To dd.Columns.Count - 1
                b.Append("<td>")
                b.Append(dd.Rows(j).Item(i).ToString)
                b.Append("</td>")
            Next
            b.Append("</tr>")
        Next

        b.Append("</table>")

        Clipboard.SetText(b.ToString())

    End Sub

    Private dd As DataTable
```

**UPDATE:**
thanks to @ClearLogic comment the issue was solved, macros in the generic workbook was the cause for that behavior. Please see the discussion below @ClearLogic marked answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend **EPPlus**. Its available on nuget.Very easy to use.

Here is a working Code snippet in c#. Translation to vb.net would not be difficult

```
using (ExcelPackage excelFile = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(fileName)))
{
    ExcelWorksheet ws = excelFile.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
    ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(datatable, true);
    for (int i = 1; i <= datatable.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        ws.Column(i).Style.HorizontalAlignment = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Left;
        ws.Column(i).AutoFit();
    }

    ws.Row(1).Style.Font.Bold = true;
    excelFile.Save();
}
```

**Edit**
 Vb.net Code

```
Using excelFile As New ExcelPackage(New FileInfo(fileName))
        Dim ws As ExcelWorksheet = excelFile.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1")
        ws.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataTable(datatable, True)
        For i As Integer = 1 To datatable.Columns.Count
            ws.Column(i).Style.HorizontalAlignment = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Left
            ws.Column(i).AutoFit()
        Next

        ws.Row(1).Style.Font.Bold = True
        excelFile.Save()
    End Using
```

Comment: thank you very much for the information and for the example, i will try it later and let you know.

Comment: ive marked your question as answer but now i cant understand why this line of code  Dim ws As ExcelWorksheet = excelFile.Workbook.Worksheets("UNITED_DB")  throws this exception: "Vba module names can't contain unicode characters" it suppose to get a string..maybe you have a clue? tnx

Comment: I could not reproduce the error with your code.I don't think this  is related to .NET code.My guess is you have defined a macro in excel on default worksheet and this error is being thrown when you are opening the excel file.

Comment: you are right i removed the macros from the open workbook event and it works. i updated your conclusion in the main thread for developers that will have that issue in the future. thank you!